# imaginary part of the multiplication of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I read a formula in a book about complex analysis:
$$\text{Im}(\prod(1+ia_k))=0$$
is equivalent to
$$\sum \arctan a_k=0 \pmod  \pi$$
I calculated cases $n=2,3$, but I don't think direct calculation is a right way. Is there any quick idea to prove it?

Thank you

Comment: What are $\alpha_k$ ? Some arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: Whata bout writing $1+ia_k$ is polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple use of [Euler's formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/eulers-formula/#:%7E:text=eix%3Dcosx,applications%20in%20physics%20and%20engineering.):

Say $1+ia_k = r_k\left(\cos\theta_k + i\sin\theta_k\right)$, for $r_k = \sqrt{1+a_k^2}$ and $\tan\theta_k = a_k$. (Refer to the Polar Form of a Complex Number).

Then,

$$\theta_k = m_k\pi + \arctan(a_k)$$ where $m_k$ is an integer.

(This signifies that $\theta_k$ belongs to a set of values.)

Now,

$$\text{Im}(\prod(1+ia_k))=0$$
By Euler's Formula, we have

$$\text{Im}\left(\prod{r_k} \cdot \prod{e^{i\theta_k}}\right)=0$$

Since $\prod{r_k} \neq 0$,

$$\Rightarrow \text{Im}\left(\prod{e^{i\theta_k}}\right)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \text{Im}\left(e^{i\sum{\theta_k}}\right)=0$$

Again, by Euler's Formula,
$$\sin\left(\sum\theta_k\right) = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum\theta_k = n\pi$$ where $n$ is an integer.

Let $M = \sum{m_k}$.

Then,

$$\sum\arctan{a_k} = \left(n - M\right)\pi$$

and the said result then follows.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the length of the proof. It is quite elementary if you understand Euler's Formula.